# Google Decode Integrity Token Error: URL not found

Tags: java, android, decode

So I managed to get the Integrity Token and Decode it as described here [Google PlayIntegrity API: a Nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193058/google-playintegrity-api-a-nightmare-solved/72511785) but now I have some bizarre situation.

I get the correct decode answer from the Google Cloud Server in my **DEBUG** version (LICENSED, UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION) running on a physical phone connected to my computer for debugging.

**DEBUG**

```json
 {DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse@11016}  size = 1
 "tokenPayloadExternal" -> {TokenPayloadExternal@11044}  size = 4
 key = "tokenPayloadExternal"
 value = {TokenPayloadExternal@11044}  size = 4
       "accountDetails" -> {AccountDetails@11052}  size = 1
          key = "accountDetails"
          value = {AccountDetails@11052}  size = 1
             "appLicensingVerdict" -> "LICENSED"
       "appIntegrity" -> {AppIntegrity@11054}  size = 4
          key = "appIntegrity"
          value = {AppIntegrity@11054}  size = 4
             "appRecognitionVerdict" -> "UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION"
             "certificateSha256Digest" -> {ArrayList@11072}  size = 1
             "packageName" -> "com.package.name"
             "versionCode" -> {Long@11076} 30707
       "deviceIntegrity" -> {DeviceIntegrity@11056}  size = 1
          key = "deviceIntegrity"
          value = {DeviceIntegrity@11056}  size = 1
             "deviceRecognitionVerdict" -> {ArrayList@11081}  size = 1
             key = "deviceRecognitionVerdict"
                value = {ArrayList@11081}  size = 1
                0 = "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY"
       "requestDetails" -> {RequestDetails@11058}  size = 3
          key = "requestDetails"
          value = {RequestDetails@11058}  size = 3
             "nonce" -> "my-nonce"
             "requestPackageName" -> "com.visacsoft.customcalc"
             "timestampMillis" -> {Long@11094} 1654386755670
```

In the **RELEASE** version with the Test group enabled to validate it, I get the correct decode response (LICENSED, PLAY_RECOGNIZED), running on a physical phone downloaded from Google Play.

**RELEASE with Test group**

```json
{DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse@23464}  size = 1
   "tokenPayloadExternal" -> {TokenPayloadExternal@23474}  size = 5
      key = "tokenPayloadExternal"
      value = {TokenPayloadExternal@23474}  size = 5
      "accountDetails" -> {AccountDetails@23483}  size = 1
         key = "accountDetails"
         value = {AccountDetails@23483}  size = 1
            "appLicensingVerdict" -> "LICENSED"
      "appIntegrity" -> {AppIntegrity@23485}  size = 4
         key = "appIntegrity"
         value = {AppIntegrity@23485}  size = 4
         "appRecognitionVerdict" -> "PLAY_RECOGNIZED"
            key = "appRecognitionVerdict"
            value = "PLAY_RECOGNIZED"
         "certificateSha256Digest" -> {ArrayList@23505}  size = 1
            key = "certificateSha256Digest"
            value = {ArrayList@23505}  size = 1
            0 = "012345678901234567890b1mYS6Y6rQ4gFUw"
         "packageName" -> "com.package.name"
            key = "packageName"
            value = "com.package.name"
         "versionCode" -> {Long@23509} 30707
            key = "versionCode"
            value = {Long@23509} 30707
      "deviceIntegrity" -> {DeviceIntegrity@23487}  size = 1
         key = "deviceIntegrity"
         value = {DeviceIntegrity@23487}  size = 1
            "deviceRecognitionVerdict" -> {ArrayList@23516}  size = 1
               key = "deviceRecognitionVerdict"
               value = {ArrayList@23516}  size = 1
                  0 = "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY"
      "requestDetails" -> {RequestDetails@23489}  size = 3
         key = "requestDetails"
         value = {RequestDetails@23489}  size = 3
            "nonce" -> "my-nonce"
               key = "nonce"
               value = "my-nonce"
            "requestPackageName" -> "com.package.name"
            "timestampMillis" -> {Long@23529} 1654368020674
```

But, if I delete the response for the Test group, in the same **RELEASE** version I get a weird error saying:

**RELEASE without Test group**

> The requested URL /v1/:decode IntegrityToken? B=com.package.name was
> not found on this server.

in an HTML page message
[image]

How can it Decode correctly for the **DEBUG** and Test **RELEASE** but it gives `The requested URL not found on this server` for the same **RELEASE** uploaded to Google Play but not in the test group??

I think I have missed some configuration somewhere, but I can't find any setting, in the Google Play Console or the Google Cloud, that fix this.

I have tried with and without the Cloud Project Number for the `IntegrityTokenResponse` getting the same error.