# How to Resolve "GoogleJsonResponseException" error while decoding playIntergrity token

Tags: java, google-api, google-play-integrity-api

I have used the java solution provided here for decrypting integrity token  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72461439/21509538, i am decrypting the token on google server and while  `"*DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse response = play.v1().decodeIntegrityToken("com.test.android.integritysample", requestObj).execute();* "` this call i am getting below error

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://playintegrity.googleapis.com/v1/com.companyname.android.qa:decodeIntegrityToken

```
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

what permission do i have to provide, do have make some changes in play console ?

I am trying to read the integrity token, with the help of below code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72461439/21509538

Answer (score 0):

As per this doc, https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/classic#decrypt-verify-google-servers

> your service account the roles of **Service Account User** and
> **Service Usage Consumer**.

In your project create a Service Account with the above roles and generate the JSON key. You can use the key to access the API.